# Windows 10 DNS settings are always resetting after a while (TCP/IPv4)

Tags: windows-10, dns, network-adapter

At some point in the past I've manually set my wifi adapter to use 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 as DNS, but I don't want to use this anymore but instead to obtain the DNS server automatically from the default gateway.
If I set it to 'obtain DNS server address automatically', it stays for a while but every now and then (after a few days) it resets itself to the setting of using 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4

I don't understand what is resetting it to these settings or why it happens. Windows 10 Pro Version 20H2. What could be going on?

[image]

Comment: Are you using some 3rd party software which intends to increase performance of your pc?

Comment: @TontyTon no, no such thing - only 'mcaffee webadvisor' but I doubt that fiddles with the network adapter

Comment: Try disabling it as several such software set DNS server to their preferred DNS servers (here, google's) in the name of security. They keep checking the DNS server used to check if it has been changed and reset, as they can't know if the DNS Server was changed by user or some malicious object.

Comment: Group policy maybe?  If you can pinpoint when it changes, that might help pin down cause.

Comment: Did you ever find the root cause? I have some users reporting the same symptom. [greg](https://superuser.com/users/1653103/greg) (this was a comment written as an answer due to reputation)

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? I'm experiencing the same issue.